# WPF C# resource updating in new window

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamicresource

I have problem with updating colors in new window.
Resource is in App.xml

```
<Application
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="EOS_Toolkit.App"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="EOS_RED" Color="#FF619C1A"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="EOS_GRAY" Color="#FF666366"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NORMAL_TEXT" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="DESC_TEXT" Color="#FF7C7C7C"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MAIN_BACKGROUND" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
```

I load templates by class and set it

```
 def = templates[name];

                if (def.eos_red != null) { Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["EOS_RED"] = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(def.eos_red)); }
                if (def.eos_gray != null) { Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["EOS_GRAY"] = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(def.eos_gray)); }
                if (def.normal_text != null) { Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["NORMAL_TEXT"] = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(def.normal_text)); }
                if (def.desc_text != null) { Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["DESC_TEXT"] = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(def.desc_text)); }
                if (def.main_background != null) { Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["MAIN_BACKGROUND"] = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(def.main_background)); }
```

I make in application sometimes while loading new window with progressbar.

```
Load loading = new Load(); // okno s progressbarem
            loading.Owner = this;
            loading.Closed += loading_done;
            this.IsEnabled = false;
            loading.Show();
            _Plugins[Convert.ToString(sender.lab_name.Text)].Load(loading.prg_load);
            loading.Hide();
            this.IsEnabled = true;
```

and here is xaml of new window

```
<Window x:Class="EOS_Toolkit.Load"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Načítaní..." Height="81" Width="300" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Topmost="True" Background="{DynamicResource MAIN_BACKGROUND}">
    <Window.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect/>
    </Window.Effect>
    <Border BorderBrush="{DynamicResource EOS_RED}" BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource EOS_RED}" Margin="0" Grid.Row="0" Stroke="{DynamicResource EOS_RED}" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Label Content="Načítaní..." Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="24" Foreground="{DynamicResource NORMAL_TEXT}" />
            <ProgressBar x:Name="prg_load" Height="10" Margin="5,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="{DynamicResource EOS_RED}" Background="#33000000" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"/>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Problem is when I load temlate and change values every colour in application is changed but this window is still in default colors.
Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that While the window is still open, you change the values of the colors, (window open on screen) the colors change in the Resources but not on the window? If so, AFAIK you need to re-render the control if you are changing its resrouces dynamically (i could be wrong). As i do not believe updates to an underlying style/resource will trigger an update. However, you could bind the Colors rather than use a `DynamicResource` which then can implement the Notify Property

Comment: No, I change values and then I create and show window.